# How can i share a NSString between classes

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsstring

Is there anyway that i can define an NSString. Inside of one class then access its value inside of another class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example...

In **global.h**

```
extern NSString *const VERSION;
```

in **global.mm**

```
#import "Global.h"
NSString *const VERSION = @"1.0.1";
```

any other source file can `#import` global.h to access the value.

Comment: Hi Hoarace ,is it necessary to include the #import "global.h" in the Application_Prefix.pch also.